# Property of Hom-functor

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

How to prove $$\operatorname{Hom}_{R}(A,\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(R,B))\cong \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(A,B)$$ where $R$ is a commutative ring, $A$ an $R$-module and $B$ an abelian group?

Is the following proof valid?

By adjunction of hom and tensor, we know, $\operatorname{Hom}_{R}(A,\operatorname{Hom}_{R}(M,B))\cong \operatorname{Hom}_{R}(A\otimes_{R}M,B)$.
Replacing $M$ by $\mathbb{Z}$, $A\otimes_{R}\mathbb{Z}\cong A$ (can we consider $\mathbb{Z}$ as a $R$-module?) and using $\operatorname{Hom}_{R}(\mathbb{Z},B)\cong \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(R,B)$ (is this valid?) we have the above result.

Comment: No (Z is not an R-module for every ring R, and your final isomorphism doesn't hold). But see the "general statement" here for a hint: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor-hom_adjunction .

Comment: not even for commutative rings? why?

Comment: Is $\mathbb{Z}$ an $\mathbb{F}_2$-module? Or a $\mathbb{C}$-module? (Note that the identity elements $1_{\mathbb{F}_2}$ and $1_{\mathbb{C}}$ must act trivially on $\mathbb{Z}$.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find explicit isomorphisms. I assume that $R$ is unitary.

- If $f:A\to B$ is a $\Bbb Z$-morphism, then let $g(a):=r\mapsto f(ra)$.
- If $g:A\to \hom_{\Bbb Z}(R,B)$ is an $R$-morphism, then $f(a):=g(a)\,(1)$.

Check that these defined mappings $g$ and $f$ are as stated, and that $f\mapsto g$ and $g\mapsto f$ inverses to each other.